# How can I change the owner of a registry folder through a .bat or. ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, permissions, windows-10, registry

I have a file which sets the startup type of a lot of unneeded services to 'Disabled?', but every time I open the `.reg` file it says I don't have permission.

There are at least 30 different keys (each service has a different subkey which has the 'Start' key in it) and if I try to just change the owner of the parent key and make the child keys inherit permissions it doesn't work.

Is it possible to somehow make them inherit the permissions? Or is there a command I can use to change the owner of each subkey?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I did have a way of changing permissions but it reqired you to already be set as owner, so I deleted it and don't remember, sorry.

Comment: How do you expect to get ownership on something if you don't have permissions to?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 By right of `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`?

Comment: Administrators have full control over the Services key and subkeys. You just need to apply your .reg file as an administrator. The default "Merge" action should request elevation.

Comment: You can manually change ownership to yourself even if you don't have permissions for some reason, i dont know why.

Comment: @eryksun It doesnt work for me, is there any way I can merge as admin specifically?

Comment: Open an elevated command prompt and run the .reg file from there.

Comment: As to changing the owner, as was already stated, the permissions dialog in regedit enables `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` if the process access token has this privilege. Administrators have this privilege for obvious reasons. Once you're the owner, NT's security model implicitly allows modifying an object's security -- unless an "OWNER RIGHTS" ACE denies this right.